# .html() method equivalent for SVG elements

Tags: jquery, xml, d3.js, svg

I have been searching for a good alternative for the .html() method for SVG elements. .html() works in Chrome and Safari, possibly Firefox, but not IE or Edge.

Below is what I want to achieve.

**HTML**

```
<svg class="root">
  <g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**JQuery**

```
import image from '/path/to/svg';

// image imported from another file, looks like <svg>...</svg>

g.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 1)
    .attr('cx', 0)
    .attr('cy', 0);
g.append('g')
    .html(image);
```

There are similar questions on SO, but answers I've found are outdated, lead to broken links, etc.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you are using D3.js, since you tagged your question as such). In D3.js `.html()` is equivalent to `.innerHTML`. It "works" in some browsers, but it's actually parsed as HTML, so it's actually a hack. If you wan't to use it anyway in a browser where it doesn't work and `.innerHTML` does, then just replace it:

```
g.node().innerHTML ="<svg><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='30' fill='red'/></svg>";
```

The [node()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_node) method returns the original DOM node (which allows you to call DOM methods and refer to DOM properties).

But a *better* way to load an SVG in D3.js is using [d3.xml()](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Requests.md#d3_xml):

```
d3.xml("sample.svg",
        function(xmlData) {

    var svg = xmlData.documentElement;
    console.log(svg);

    // do something with the imported SVG
}
```

From there you can append it to the `<g>` using DOM:

```
g.node().appendChild(svg);
```